# Alpha compositing wrong when rendering to QGLFrameBufferObject vs screen

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, opacity

I'm having a problem when rendering even simple shapes with partial opacity to QGLFrameBufferObjects in Qt.

I have reduced the problem down to this:

When I render a simple quad to a QGLFrameBufferObject with color set to (1,0,0,.5), and then blit that to the screen, I get a result that is way too light a red for 50% opacity.  If I draw the same quad with the same color (same code, in fact) directly to the screen, I get the correct color value.  If I render the quad with opacity == 1.0, then the results are the same...I get a full, deep red in both cases.  I've confirmed that the color is really wrong in the buffer by dumping the buffer to disk directly with buffer.toImage().save("/tmp/blah.tif").

In both cases, I've cleared the output buffer to (1,1,1,1) before performing the operation.

Why are things I draw that are partially transparent coming out lighter when drawn to an offscreen buffer than if I draw them right to the screen?  There must be some state that I have to set on the FBO or something, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Alpha does not mean "transparent." It doesn't mean *anything* at all. It only takes up a meaning when *you* give it one. It only mean "transparent" when you set up a blend mode that uses alpha to control transparency. So if you didn't [set up a blend mode](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) that [creates the effect of transparency](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting), then alpha is just another color component that will be written exactly as is to the framebuffer.

Comment: If what you say is truly the source of my problem, then you're saying that my blend mode has been set up correctly when drawing to the screen, and yet not when drawing to an offscreen buffer.  And yet, the only difference between the two cases is that I've created an offscreen buffer and bound it to my current context.  So what would explain my blend mode being right in one case and wrong in the other.  Is there a blend mode specific to the offscreen buffer that I need to set up independently of the rest of my environment?

Comment: @Steve: `So what would explain my blend mode being right in one case and wrong in the other.` Your code having a bug in it. But you didn't show your code, so I can't say.